# hsqldb plugin for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, hsqldb

I want to add the eclipse plugin for HSQLdb.

WHAT I DID :
I have downloaded HSQLdb plugin from http://sourceforge.net/projects/hsqldb-plugin/files/

then i followed steps mentioned in a blog http://jobinwilson.blogspot.in/2010/05/adding-hsqldb-plugin-to-eclipse.html as

3.Unzip the HSQLDBPlugin zip,you will get two folders hsqldb.core and hsqldb.ui
4.Copy both the folders into ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins folder
5.Navigate to ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins/hsqldb.ui folder from command prompt/shell
6.run the command jar cvf ui.jar -C bin . (note the ending dot,denotes the current folder).This command will generate ui.jar
7.restart eclipse

After doing this, the option of HSQLdb has populated in the menu, but when I am trying to do "Add Database Engine Nature", am getting an error.

ERROR:

Cannot add HSQLDb Engine nature:
org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow can not be cast to 
org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow

If anyone has faced the same issue or knows how to resolve it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely is due to the fact that the plugin was last updated in 2004. Apparently some Eclipse library APIs have changed since then. There's a newer version here:

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/309316#.UG06fK44J6Y