# HSQLDB Plug-In for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hsqldb

I want to add the eclipse plugin for HSQLdb. I followed the instructions given here: [hsqldb plugin for eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722196/hsqldb-plugin-for-eclipse)

Got the same problem: 
"ERROR:

Cannot add HSQLDb Engine nature: org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow can not be cast to org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow"

The proposed solution was to import newer version from Eclipse market place:
"There's a newer version here:

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/309316#.UG06fK44J6Y"

Unfortunately, that did not work for me. What have might gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The Marketplace version you reference says it is compatible with Eclipse 3.* so it should work with Eclipse 3.8 and earlier.

The error you are getting appears to be because the code is relying on internal Eclipse classes which have been changed in Eclipse 4.x (specifically `org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow` which no longer extends `org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow`). This can only be resolved by rewriting the HSQLdb plugin.